# How can I make the animations smooth in Blend Tree?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is that when my character changes direction (while moving forward press the back button) the character first abruptly switches to the idle animation, and only then starts running backwards. It turns out not smooth, but abrupt transition. I have not found an answer to this question. Also, I don't know if using idle and running in the same blend tree is the right approach.

Screenshot of the blend tree settings:

[image]

And my character movement script:

```
private CharacterController _controller;
private Animator _animator;

private float speed = 5f;

private float xInput;
private float yInput;


private void Start()
{
    _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private void Update()
{
    xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    yInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Move();
}

private void Move()
{
    float scaledMoveSpeed = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    Vector3 moveDirection = transform.right * xInput + transform.forward * yInput;

    _animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", moveDirection.x);
    _animator.SetFloat("Vertical", moveDirection.z);

    _controller.Move(moveDirection * scaledMoveSpeed);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a pretty obvious answer.** You can use `Vector3.SmoothDamp` to make smooth input values (especially relevant for new input system) and also pass it in animator parameters, so that values don't become 0 abruptly.